# Is there a way to only import certain objects form a JSON website in Python?

Tags: python, json, url

I am working on a project and I need to import like 200 BIG lists from different URLs. This takes around 3 seconds for each and I cant wait that long for the program to finish. But there is only two objects in the website for each one that I need, so I am wondering if there is a way to import ONLY those two objects instead of the entire JSON from each URL.

Answer (score 0):

First, is it downloading the docs that is taking the time, or parsing them in Python once you have them?  Better measure.  If it's downloading, there's not much you can do unless the source APIs provide a way to request only part of the documents.

If parsing is the bottleneck, you still have to parse (there's no way to zero in on a part of a JSON doc without parsing), but you might try going to a non-Python parser for that part of the task only, like invoking command-line [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) through Subprocess.